# Rails Console not working after implementing omniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have implemented omniauth with Facebook, and now I wanted to verify it by checking my database, but I am unable in login to my rails console. I am unable to understand what's the main problem, since console is working for other projects. The error is as follows:

```
rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 2278
/Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': dlopen(/Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:138:in `require_command!'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `block in require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/Documents/cwPakistan/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the spring preloader is already running/didn't shut down.

Try `bin/spring stop` or just `spring stop`

Comment: @AyazAhmadTarar - if you try `bundle exec rails c` what happens?

Comment: `Running via Spring preloader in process 6146
/Users/userx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': dlopen(/Users/userx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/x86_64-darwin15/readline.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib (LoadError)`

Comment: Ah, looks like an irb dependency isn't loading.

Try adding `gem ’rb-readline’` to your Gemfile, then `bundle install`, then try `rails c`